# Not a real issue (typo in URL) - Netezza pySpark connection fails while DbVisualizer works

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, netezza, windows-10-desktop

**Update:** This has been resolved. It was a typo in the URL.

--
I'm trying to read data from Netezza using pyspark on Windows 10 1909.

I can read from it using DbVisualizer no problem. Then I tried running `pyspark --driver-class-path <path to nzjdbc.jar> --jars <path to nzjdbc.jar> --master local[*]` (same machine, VPN connection, JDBC driver jar, and all).

I used this code from the pyspark shell:

```py
dataframe = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
    url="jdbc:netezza://<server>:5480/<database>",
    dbtable="ADMIN.<table>",
    user="***",
    password="***",
    driver="org.netezza.Driver",
).load()
```

but this fails for me, with the following stack, after about 10-20 seconds (I also tried adding `queryTimeout="300"`, but that didn't make a difference):

```
"...\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spark\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.load.
: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.netezza.sql.NzConnection.initSocket(NzConnection.java:2859)
        at org.netezza.sql.NzConnection.open(NzConnection.java:293)
        at org.netezza.datasource.NzDatasource.getConnection(NzDatasource.java:675)
        at org.netezza.datasource.NzDatasource.getConnection(NzDatasource.java:662)
        at org.netezza.Driver.connect(Driver.java:155)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

A coworker is able to run the same code from his Mac with no issues (also on VPN).

Is there something in Windows or in Netezza itself that could affect what clients are able connect to Netezza? Or could I be missing something in the `pyspark` command?

Comment: Try disabling the firewall on you computer (temporarily) and se if that helps?

Comment: Thanks @Lars G Olsen. It was me the whole time, I made a typo in the URL

Comment: Lol, I’m the cause for  ‘error 40’ all the time (40 cm is reputedly the distance the user has from the screen)

Comment: @LarsGOlsen Yeah, you'd think one'd learn after having made this kind of mistake a bunch of times in the past. In my defense, I think it was a typo that wasn't obvious right away b/c the word I misspelled seems to have other spellings, and typos in strings are notoriously hard to catch as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a typo in my URL. That was a really sneaky one

Comment: I can't seem to delete this question even though I doubt anyone will find it helpful

Comment: That’s ok, your ‘remember to spell-check URL’ is not an uncommon solution, and timeouts can be many other things :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing - a spell check wouldn't have caught this one. It would really help if the exception had a more helpful message, like "DNS resolution failed" or something

Answer (score 1):

Can you try increasing the LoginTimeout value ? FYI queryTimeout refers to timeout for a single query.

Comment: Where do I change that? I don't see it as an option in SparkSession.read.jdbc

Comment: After some more digging, I am assuming you meant to add it to the URL. I'll try that, though the default as per IBM's website is supposed to be infinite

Comment: As I suspected, that wasn't it. It does throw "Login timed out" for very small values of `loginTimeout`, but if I bump it up even a little bit, it's back to square one, with the original exception. Thanks for the idea, though!